# Android ScrollView not working

Tags: java, android, scrollview

I have a layout which I want to be scrollable when content is overflowing the screen.
I have the following layout xml set up.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView android:id="@+id/ScrlView" 
     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:isScrollContainer="false"
    android:id="@+id/home_root"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/backrepeat">
        <!-- Include Header  -->
        <include layout="@layout/main_header"/>

        <!--  Include dashboard -->
        <include layout="@layout/dashboard"/>   



</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

A dashboard is a collection of icons serving as a menu. Example: [click me](http://2.bp.blogspot.com/_uJSd5DrlOrg/TPqpWWZV6vI/AAAAAAAABJA/EpirfqZZCnw/s1600/dashboard_header.png)
Unfortunately, the second include (dashboard) shows 'broken' now. See screen:
[Click here](http://i48.tinypic.com/193401.png)

As you can see it doesn't look like it's suposed to. When I delete the scrollview, everything is fine.

What I want is for my dashboard to still look good, but be scrollable if needed.
I tried several setups but all give the same result. What am I doing wrong?

Any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: try to remove the android:isScrollContainer="false", and add android:fillViewport="true"  to scrollView

Comment: though, does it always have to be there?

Comment: @TomerMor if you copy/paste that as an Answer, I'd upvote it - worked perfectly, solved the problem for me too.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `android:isScrollContainer="false"`, and add `android:fillViewport="true"` to `scrollView`